# Android ListView getView() called on touch

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I have a camera activity (AR) where I put inside it a view (I call it A) with 2 listview, I can drag this view (A) inside or outside the screen for show or hide it, my problem is that If I "hide" this view (A) dragging it outside the window and I touch the screen I see that the touch event call adapter getView(), this isn't a big problem but is a useless process...why the touch of an external view call adapter getView()?how can I solve it?the 2 list view are inside a LinearLayout with MATCH_PARENT attribute for width and height.
Here my view:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="3" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="7"
    android:weightSum="16"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/top_frame">



        <FrameLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:background="@color/azzurro"
            android:id="@+id/download_view">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="3 PRODOTTI SELEZIONATI"
                android:id="@+id/text_selected"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textSize="8dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="Vuoi procedere con il download?"
                android:id="@+id/text_proced_download"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="120dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
                android:textSize="8dp"
                android:textColor="@color/blu_background" />

            <Button
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="ok"
                android:id="@+id/btn_start"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="8dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:background="@color/blu_background"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
                android:textSize="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:background="#ffd2d5d4"
                android:textColor="#ff5c5d5d" />


            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@color/white">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="16dp"
                    android:layout_height="16dp"
                    android:text="X"
                    android:id="@+id/btn_close"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_scarica"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:textSize="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/chiudi"
                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp" />
            </FrameLayout>

        </FrameLayout>






        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:id="@+id/normal_view">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="PRODOTTI 0/5"
                android:id="@+id/text_toDownlaod"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textSize="9dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:background="@color/blu_background"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="Scarica più prodotti"
                android:id="@+id/text_scarica"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textSize="9dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_toDownlaod"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:lines="2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
                android:textColor="#ff8b8b8b" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="16dp"
                android:text="X"
                android:id="@+id/btn_close_1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_scarica"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:textSize="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/chiudi"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:cropToPadding="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
        </FrameLayout>


    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/collection_select_product_frame">



    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and:

```
hList.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
hList.setMinimumHeight(collection_select_product_frame.getHeight());
hList.setOrientation(TwoWayView.Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
hList.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
collection_select_product_frame.addView(hList);
```

Comment: Similar issue I am facing. I am calling notifyDataSetChanged() but the list is not updated. But once I press on list view, it's getView() method is called and refresh the list. Don't know what hell is going on? Are you able to find out the issue?